# Generate distinct random numbers using procedural code

Tags: php

I have been trying to generate distinct random numbers using procedural code. But i am failing to do it. Please help me in this regard. thanks in advance.

```
<?php 

$rnd_array = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$a = 1;
for ($i=0; $a <= 10 ; $i++)
{
    echo $rnd = rand() % 10;
    echo "\t \t";

    for ($j=0; $j < 10 ; $j++)
    { 
        if ($rnd == $rnd_array[$j])
        {
            $flag = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $flag = false;
        }
    }
    if ($flag == false)
    {
        $rnd_array[$a] = $rnd;
        $a++;
    }
}

echo "<br> <br>";

for ($k=0; $k < 10 ; $k++)
{
    echo $rnd_array[$k];
    echo "\t \t";
}
?>
```

Comment: So you just want 11 random numbers, without duplicates ? (BTW: Right now are you trying to create 11 random numbers, which can be between 0-9, and when you are trying to get them without duplicates, this will be pretty hard :)

Comment: the problem is if it found the same number in array then it skipped that index of array and showing initial value 0.

Comment: @WebPlayers Please explain more, what exactly you are trying to archive and what your expected output would be!

Comment: @WebPlayers, enclose the inner block within a "do-while", to loop until you get a non-repeated random number, like `do { rnd = rand() % 10; . . . while ( $flag )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 distincts random numbers

```
    <?php 

$numbers = array();
$i = 0;

while($i < 10){
    $new = rand();
    $known = false;
    foreach($numbers as $key => $value){
        if($value == $new ){
            $known = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$known){
        $numbers[$i]=$new;
        $i++;
    }


}

var_dump($numbers);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a somewhat different logic - start with an empty array, generate a random number, put it into the array if the array doesn't already contain it. Repeat until your array contains as many elements as you want it to.

Here's a simple example:

```
$num = 10;
$min = 1;
$max = 100;

$array = [];
while (count($array) < $num) {
    $random = mt_rand($min, $max);
    if (!in_array($random, $array)) {
        $array[] = $random;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because array length is equal to range of generated random value

```
$rnd_array = range(0,9);
shuffle($rnd_array);

print_r($rnd_array);

Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 8
)
```

Comment: @WebPlayers As long as we don't know what you are trying to do, why can't fix your code..

Comment: @Web Players 1st for loop change $a to $i  `for ($i=0; $i <= 10 ; $i++)`